# Is BDD a replacement of TDD?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I wonder whether [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) is a replacement of [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)? What I understand now is that in an ultimate BDD we don't have unit tests any more. Instead there are stories/scenarios/features and "test steps". And it looks like a complete replacement of TDD for me. TDD is dead?

Comment: Not really. BDD *extends* TDD - if I understand correctly, one of the main points is to allow non-programmers to participate better in TDD. The tests still need to be coded at some point, but it should become clearer what is the *purpose* of the tests (as opposed to the mere *function*).

Comment: Even in the Wikipedia article you linked they say: [BDD] extends TDD by writing test cases in a natural language that non-programmers can read.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not at all. BDD is just a variant of TDD.

In TDD, you formulate your requirements as an executable test, then write the production code to fulfill the test. BDD does nothing but re-formulate these requirements into a more human-readable form and thus makes the tests somewhat more verbose to a human reader who looks at the test report. (Btw: To achieve this, BDD requires way more code than traditional data-driven unit testing...)

That's all.

Thomas

Comment: BDD *at a scenario level* requires more code than unit testing. At a unit testing level it can be much more concise, since the language helps you eliminate duplication and focus on the behavior you're really interested in. I offer examples of this, at a scenario level: http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs and at a unit level: http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/WiPFlash.Behavior/Framework/WaiterBehaviour.cs

Answer (score 9):

I have a different viewpoint on this than other responders.

Dan North created BDD druing his consulting work on TDD when he saw, that many people were confused by the "test" part, because they had testing experience, he decided to change the name. So at first, BDD was exactly what TDD is, explained correctly.
After that Dan started to extend the idea of using executable specifications (unit tests) to drive the implementations by adding another levels of specification. He was inspired by user stories, so the simplest BDD implemented by most tools lets you write requirements as user story scenarios, than you write code which generates unit tests and than from those unit tests you work on implementation. So now you see compared to TDD there is another level of specification - user stories. Many tools include prepared translations of user stories to tests, so many forget about them as you did, but they are still there and cannot be fully omitted - practically and also theoretically as noted, programming user stories is not efficient. But that is not the point, you use user stories to gather requirements from stakeholders and to proove you implemented them by executing acceptance tests.

There are many other small things in BDD, you better read Dans blog to understand them, but the main point is that BDD is an extension of TDD even outside the implementation phase, so they cannot be interchanged or rendered useless by each other.

Answer (score 5):

Gabriel is almost right.

The fundamental difference at a unit level is that BDD uses the word "should" instead of "test". It turns out that when you say "test", most people start thinking about what their code does, and how they can test it. With BDD, we consider - and question - what our code *should* do. It's a subtle but important point, and if you want to know why that's powerful, go read up on Neuro-linguistic Programming - particularly around the way in which words affect thoughts and the model of the world. As a brief example, many people who are new to TDD start pinning their code down so that nobody can break it. BDDers tend to provide examples which demonstrate the value of their code so that people can change their code safely.

Dan realised while he was talking with Chris Matts and writing JBehave that he could take this up to a scenario level (scenarios aren't quite the same as stories). Because we were already using "should" at a unit level, it made sense to start writing things in English (I tend to use "should give me" rather than "should return", for instance). Acceptance Test Driven Development - ATDD - has been around for a long time, but this was AFAIK the first time anyone had written them in English with business stakeholders involved.

It's more than just a replacement for TDD. It's a different way of thinking about testing - very much focused on learning, deliberately discovering areas where we perhaps thought we knew what we were doing but didn't, uncovering and helping us to resolve ignorance and misunderstanding. It works at many levels. Chris Matts' Feature Injection takes this into the higher level space, right the way up to project visioning.

We still do write examples - or specifications if you like - at a unit level too, but really, it's a pattern which goes far higher than even scenarios. If you want to know more you [might find my blog useful](http://lizkeogh.com/category/bdd/), [Dan's is even better](http://blog.dannorth.net/). Also, [Chris has a comic book on Real Options](http://www.lulu.com/product/file-download/real-options-at-agile-2009/5949486) which outlines some of the patterns I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

BDD is not about replacing TDD. It is about giving some more structure and deciplene to your TDD practices. The hardest thing about TDD is that developers without the bigger picture hardly have clue on what to test and how much to test. BDD provides a very concrete guideline with this gray area. Check out this post,

http://codingcraft.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/bdd-get-your-tdd-right/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the advantages of BDD over TDD are:

- Decoupling the tests from the implementation details. So the feature files won't break, just the step files, if you modify the implementation, but not the behavior.
- Reusing existing testing code. You can do the same by TDD, if you define custom assertions, fixtures, helpers, etc... But we (at least I) usually copy-paste testing code (bad habit). It is much easier to reuse code by BDD. There will be still some repetition, but at least it will be in gherkin.

Everything else goes the same way as normally by TDD. So you can use any assertion lib in the step definitions you would use in the unit tests. The only difference that you added another abstraction level by separating what (feature description in gherkin) from how (step definitions in a programming language) in your testing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the term "[Specification by Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_by_example)" for BDD, which emphasis an important aspect of this methodology: Specifying collaboratively - through all-team specification workshops, smaller meetings or teleconference reviews. Within these sessions with different stakeholders, concrete examples are used to illustrate requirements. Discussing requirements in the form of examples helps to create a shared understanding of the problem domain and possible solutions.

By accident specifications with examples are well suited for test automation. As a result you usually improve test coverage. But this methodology also helps to [involve non-technical stakeholders](http://concordion.org). The tools that help you [create business readable input](http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2010/03/classifying-bdd-tools-unit-test-driven.html) are by nature not related to programming languages, but often based on [simple document formats](http://concordion.org/dotnet/) that are easily understandable by many people.

Answer (score 0):

BDD should emphasize behavior from a user perspective and is ideally suited to drive end-to-end tests, a kind of poor man's DSL for acceptance test driven development. It can complement TDD but it definitely is not a substitute. TDD is as much a design activity as it is a testing activity (Code that is poorly designed is difficult to test -> unit tests encourage good design). BDD has nothing to do with design. It is a kind of testing that abstracts away from the code altogether.

In practice BDD results in a lot more boiler-plate code under the hood than normal acceptance tests, therefore I prefer creating an internal DSL in a normal programming language to drive my acceptance tests. As for unit tests, BDD emphasizes behavior from a user perspective and therefore should not be used at the unit level.

BDD is an attempt to bridge the communication gap between business stake holders and programmers. In some areas it can be useful, such as banking applications where attention to detail on things like interest rate calculations is important, and requires direct input from domain experts. IMHO BDD is not the panacea that some of it's acolytes claim it is and should only be used if there is a compelling reason to do so.